# Combining multi-pattern with conditionals in match

Tags: rust

I'm trying to check if a variable `b` of a type `Option<A>` is equal to `a` of the same type `A` or `None`. It would seem idiomatic to use a `match` statement with multi pattern `Some(a) | None`, but I can't find a way to make it work.

Is there a way to express this pattern using `match` or should I just use a normal `if` pattern?

Example (also in https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=217b4559a73d59409f1d6afe7365d57c):

```
fn main() {
    let a = 3;
    let b = Some(5);
    
    // Works but has code duplication
    match b {
        Some(b_val) if b_val == a => {
            println!("do something");
        }
        None => {
            println!("do something");
        }
        Some(_) => {
            println!("do something else");
        }
    }
    
    // Works but not very idiomatic
    if b.is_none() || b.unwrap() == a {
        println!("do something");
    } else {
        println!("do something else");
    }
    
    // Does not work
    match b {
        Some(b_val) if b_val == a | None => {
            println!("do something");
        }
        Some(_) => {
            println!("do something else");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if Some(a) == b {...} else {...}` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can only come up with a const `a`:

```rust
fn main() {
    const a: i32 = 3;
    let b = Some(5);
    
    match b {
        Some(a) | None  => {
            println!("do something");
        }
        _ => {
            println!("do something else");
        }
    }
}
```

Or use `if`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 3;
    let b = Some(5);
    
    if b == None || b == Some(a) {
        println!("do something");
    } else {
        println!("do something else");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
do something else
```

Comment: Unfortunately in my real-world scenario `a` is not `const` so I guess the `if` pattern is good enough, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check inequality instead of equality:

```
match b {
    Some(b_val) if b_val != a => {
        println!("do something else");
    }
    _ => {
        println!("do something");
    }
}
```